# File related operations python subprocess vs. native python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I have a simple task I want to perform over ssh: return all files from a given file list that do not exist.

The way I would go about doing this would be to wrap the following in an ssh session:

`for f in $(files); do stat $f > /dev/null ;done`

The stdout redirect will ignore all good files and then reading the stderr will give me a list of all non found files.

I first thought of using this bash code with the ssh part inside a `subprocess.run(..., shell=True)` but was discouraged to do so. Instead,`paramiko`was suggested.

I try to understand why and when native python is better than subprocessing bash

1. Computability with different OS (not an issue for me as the code is pretty tightly tied to Ubuntu)
2. Error and exception handling - this one I do get and think it's important, though catching an exception or exit code from subprocess is kinda easy too

The con in my eyes with native python is the need to involve somewhat complicated modules such as paramiko when bash's ssh and stat seem to me as more plain and easy to use

Are there any guidelines for when and how to choose bash over python?

*This question is mainly about using a command over ssh, but is relevant for any other command that bash is doing in a short and easy way and python wraps*

Comment: `paramiko` is an SSH library—what does that have to do with forming a command to run on the other side?

Comment: I'm asking about using paramiko for the ssh connection vs using subprocess.run('ssh ... ')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really three choices here: doing something **in-process** (like `paramiko`), running `ssh` **directly** (with `subprocess`), and running `ssh` with the **shell** (also with `subprocess`).  As a general rule, avoid running the shell programmatically (as opposed to, say, upon interactive user request).

The reason is that it’s a **human-oriented interface** (thus the easy separation of words with spaces and shortcuts for `$HOME` and globbing) that is vastly underpowered as an API.  Consider, for example, how your code would detect that `ssh` was missing: the situation doesn’t arise with `paramiko` (so long as *it* is installed), is obvious with `subprocess`, and is just an (ambiguous) **exit code** and stderr message from the shell.  Also consider how you supply the command to run: it already must be a command suitable for the shell (due to limitations in the SSH protocol), but if you invoke `ssh` *with* the shell it must be **encoded** (sometimes called “doubly escaped”) so as to have the local shell’s interpretation be the desired multi-word command for the remote shell.

So far, `paramiko` and `subprocess` are pretty much equivalent.  As a more difficult case, consider how a key verification failure would manifest: `paramiko` would *describe* the failure as **data**, whereas the others would attempt to interact with the user (which might or might not be present).  `paramiko` also supports opening multiple channels over one authenticated connection; `ssh` does so as well but only via a complicated `ControlMaster` configuration involving Unix socket files (which might not have any good place to exist in some deployments).  Speaking of configuration, you may need to pass `-F` to avoid complications from the user’s `.ssh/config` if it is not designed with this automated use case in mind.

In summary, libraries are **designed** for use cases like yours, and so it should be no surprise that they work better, especially for edge cases, than assembling your own interface from human-oriented commands (although it is very useful that such manual compositions are *possible*!).  If installing a non-standard dependency like `paramiko` is a burden, at *least* use `subprocess` directly; cutting out the second shell is already a great improvement.

Comment: 1. Didn't understand the difference between running subprocess and running shell (2nd and 3rd options). Both of them are using subprocess, no?   2. I see your point but having hard time accepting it, as it explains how paramiko is great for edge cases. However I'm quite convinced there won't be any. I know the machine I run on. I install dependencies before (as part of a install and config phase) and besides, if that would have failed due to lack of ssh for example, the whole app would be dead much sooner, so I don't see it as a real issue. Can you convince me?

Comment: @CIsForCookies: Using `subprocess` without `shell=True` is equivalent to what the shell does to start a command.  Using `shell=True` does that work to start the command `/bin/sh` just so that it can parse your string (which you hopefully escaped correctly…) and do that same work *again* to run the real command (and report errors poorly).  It’s true that the differences are minor when everything works the way you think it will, but of course things misbehave and it’s very helpful to, say, be able to reliably and automatically distinguish between `ssh`’s error messages and `stat`’s.